# how to use PyQt5 QtMultimedia

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

Some people seems to be able to use QtMultimedia with PyQt5.
according to old stackoverflow posts, it was not included with PyQt5 so
what's the way to get it together?

I'm using linux (ubuntu 14.04) and PyQt5 is already installed.

Comment: [python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, QtMultimedia is very much alive and well in PyQt5. Please see the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html).

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import {See Partial List Below}
```

**Partial List of QtMultimedia Imports**

- QAudioEncoderSettings
- QCamera
- QCameraImageCapture
- QImageEncoderSettings
- QMediaMetaData
- QMediaRecorder
- QMultimedia
- QVideoEncoderSettings

In Fact, if you look at the examples directory in the PyQt5 source, you will find a couple of examples including a *video player*, *web camera application*, m*usic player* etc. @baoboa, who isn't Phil Thompson from Riverbank Computing has added the source to Github which you can find here: https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/multimediawidgets

Comment: yes I saw this tutorial, very good by the way!
I did compile PyQt5 some months ago because it wasn't part of the package handle by my distro, but it is now and everything works fine, cheers!